# Getting Deprecation Warning only but not the result or any error when using the findByIdAndUpdate method in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
require('mongoose')
const User = require('../src/models/users');

User.findByIdAndUpdate('5e2fd89f475fd04adb5f938c',{age:35}).then((user)=>{
    console.log(user);
    return User.countDocuments({age:35})
}).then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```

I have a User model and I'm trying to update the age by using the findByIdAndUpdate method provided by Mongoose ODM. All I'm getting on the console is a Deprecation Warning and not the result or Error. Nor is the age updated.

Contents of mongoose.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api',{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useFindAndModify:false
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your are passing `id` as `object`. While `findByIdAndUpdate` expects it to `string`. You can try this:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate('5e2fd89f475fd04adb5f938c',{age:35}).then((user)=>{
    console.log(user);
    return User.countDocuments({age:35})
}).then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: It was an error which I corrected and passed the Id as string later on but still the same issue.